# Why initialValue of ThreadLocal doesn't increment my variables?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, java-threads

I am learning about multithreading; and I have the following `ThreadID` class:

```
public class ThreadID {

    private static volatile int nextID=0;

    private static class ThreadLocalID extends ThreadLocal<Integer>{
        protected synchronized Integer initialValue(){
            return nextID ++;
        }
    }

    private static ThreadLocalID threadID =new ThreadLocalID();

    public static int get(){
        return threadID.get();
    }

    public static void set (int index){
        threadID.set(index);
    }
}
```

and the following `Thread` class:

```
class MyThread1 extends Thread {
    int x;
    public ThreadID tID;
    public int myid;

    public MyThread1(String name) {
        tID = new ThreadID();
        myid = tID.get();
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("la thread =" + tID.get() + " myid= " + myid);
        try {
            this.sleep(10);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("la thread =" + tID.get() + "   apres le sommeil ");
    }
}
```

and my `main` Class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyThread1 TH[] = new MyThread1[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        TH[i] = new MyThread1("nom" + i);
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) TH[i].start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) TH[i].join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
```

**Question:**

What I want is to give each Thread an `ID`; I found that when I init the `id` in the thread constructor the value is always `0` (normally the `initialValue` should increment the `nextID`)

```
la thread =1 myid= 0
la thread =3 myid= 0
la thread =2 myid= 0
```

but when I init the `id` inside the `Run` function it works !

```
la thread =1 myid= 1
la thread =3 myid= 3
la thread =2 myid= 2
```

Can any one explain why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want is to give each Thread an ID I found that when I init the
> id in the thread constructor the value is always 0 (normally the
> initialValue should increment the  nextID)

So in the `MyThread1` class constructor you do:

```
public MyThread1(String name) {
    tID = new ThreadID();
    myid = tID.get();
}
```

In this case, the thread actually calling `tID.get();` is the *main* thread, *i.e.*, the thread that is calling those constructors, from the main class:

```
MyThread1 TH[] = new MyThread1[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    TH[i] = new MyThread1("nom" + i);
```

The first call to `tID.get()` will generate a new `ID` as `0`, since it is the first time that any thread is calling `tID.get()`. The next calls from the same thread (*i.e.,* main thread) will not generate a new `ID`, but instead, it always returns the same ID, in this case, return `0` for the *main* thread.

> but when I init the id inside the Run function it works!

Inside the `run` method:

```
public void run() {
    System.out.println("la thread =" + tID.get() + " myid= " + myid);
    try {
        this.sleep(10);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("la thread =" + tID.get() + "   apres le sommeil ");
}
```

the  `tID.get()` will be called by different threads, and that is why you get new IDs. One new ID *per* thread calling for the first time `tID.get()`.